# Is it idiomatic to say "I am here just to listen"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Imagine that, my friends are talking about something. Because I know few about that topic. I want to just listening.

1. I am here just listening.
2. I am here just to listen.
3. I am here just for listening.

Which one is more idiomatic for this kind of situation?

Are there other better expressions for this situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the three you posted, the second one is the most idiomatic.

"I am here just to listen" would be understood to mean what you want - to learn about the topic from more knowledgeable friends.

But you could specify "I am here just to listen and learn" - English expressions love alliteration (the same consonant starting consecutive words) and this would also indicate you are not eavesdropping, more looking to learn.

(As a side note, you said: "Because I know few about that topic" which is incorrect. A better expression would be "Because I know little about that topic". "Few" is for countable things, whereas knowledge is not countable.)